# Requesting extended permissions for a Facebook Connect application (xFBML)

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I have an iframed xfbml application on Facebook and I am attempting to prompt users to allow "email" and "stream_publish" permissions.  However, I find that for some reason my app is not allowed to ask for extended permissions.  No matter what permission I attempt to prompt the user for it always pop up with "The application must ask for a valid extended permission."

I am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Facebook.showPermissionDialog("stream_publish, email", function(){alert('next')});
</script>
```

I have attempted requesting every type of extended permission individually and have gotten the same error.

This makes me believe there is some type of administrative step I need to go through before my application will be allowed to use extended_permissions.  Do I need to publish to the application directory?  Cross some metric threshold?

Thanks,
Macy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is nothing called stream_publish , the correct permission tag is publish_stream. use this:

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream,read_stream,email",...
```